# AWS EC2 instance is pushing an HTML file on port 8000, but I can't view it from my local browser

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, flask, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecr

I am by no means an AWS or networking/server expert, so please forgive my ignorance in the description below.

I currently have a Flask app running inside a Docker container within an EC2 instance, but cannot view it externally in a web browser when going to the EC2 instance's public IPv4 address (either http or https versions, with and without the `:8000` port indicator). When I SSH into the instance and do `curl localhost:8000` it shows the whole HTML document as expected, which makes me think that it's an EC2 issue and not a Docker issue (otherwise `curl` in EC2 would not show the HTML script, right?).

In the security group assigned to the instance, I have the outbound rules set to `all` for Type, Protocol, and Port range; with destination as 0.0.0.0/0. For inbound rules I have HTTP>TCP>80, HTTPS>TCP>443, and SSH>TCP>22, all with Source of 0.0.0.0/0.

In case it matters at all, the EC2 instance is based on an Amazon Linux 2023 AMI with ARM64 architecture (to match the docker container created on a Mac). The Docker container runs Ubuntu 22.04 and Python 3.10.12.

At this point I'm completely lost. I don't know what I'm missing, but obviously it's pretty crucial for being able to see the app. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

---

EDIT: Thanks to Andres, the solution was to add a Security Group Inbound rule to allow traffic through port range 8000 and source 0.0.0.0/0

Comment: "cannot view it externally" - what does it mean exactly? Do you have any errors? Timeouts? Your question lacks details and is unclear.

Comment: I was referring to being able to access it from the internet using just a URL (rather than being in the EC2 instance via SSH)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to allow port `8000` in your Security Group's inbound rules and access the app from your local machine like this

```
http://{ec2-ip}:8000
```

Replace `{ec2-ip}` with the public IP of your EC2 Instance.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some ways to debug.

1. Verify Firewall settings allow port 8000 outbound in Amazon Linux.
2. Verify your ec2 is in the public subnet.

Shortcut: If your ec2 has a public IP then it is in a public subnet.

3. Verify port 8000 is enabled in the Security Group. Try doing it explicitly.